# why does my side bar disappear on zooming out?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, sidebar

My website : web.njit.edu/~dp257/boilerplate/website.html

when out zooming to 50% my links/side bar disappear, here is the html code what should the html code be for the sidebar to keep it there and like resize? If you want me to post my current css let me know.

```
 <div id = "wrapper">
        <header id="name" align="center">MY IS117 Website</header>
         <div id="primary_links" align="center">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Menu 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Menu 4</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Menu 5</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

            <div id="content">
                <h1>Heading 1</h1>
                <h2>Heading 2</h2>
                <h3>Heading 3</h3>
                <h4>Heading 4</h4>
                <h5>Heading 5</h5>
                <h6>Heading 6</h6>
        <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque velit eros, lacinia non mauris at, facilisis iaculis sem. Aenean eu felis elit. Aenean nec sem ac lectus aliquet sagittis eget sit amet urna. Etiam in dignissim nulla. In non nibh pharetra, posuere mi venenatis, consequat ipsum. Quisque dapibus porttitor posuere. Maecenas porttitor nibh sit amet lacinia vehicula. Nullam sit amet urna gravida, gravida leo vel, ultrices ante. Sed accumsan nibh nec erat dapibus, ut ultrices nisi elementum. Praesent in enim at nunc consectetur cursus. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Curabitur quis scelerisque ipsum. Quisque vulputate consectetur egestas. Etiam non tincidunt urna.
        </p>
        <p>
        Aenean fringilla sed urna a ultrices. Aliquam non augue in libero venenatis sodales at ut eros. Nunc ac arcu a justo luctus ultricies. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Maecenas sed molestie leo, vel placerat massa. Nullam at eros ac nunc malesuada fermentum nec vel mi. Nulla convallis mattis facilisis. Vivamus urna quam, tincidunt id venenatis in, porttitor quis lectus. Donec eu vehicula quam, sit amet sollicitudin risus. Nullam nec dapibus tortor. Nam in consectetur urna. Aenean enim eros, ullamcorper vitae mauris at, sollicitudin blandit felis. Ut ac odio blandit, sodales tortor sed, aliquam est.
        </p>
        <p>
        Praesent at sagittis augue. Sed libero ipsum, pharetra eget ante nec, laoreet tempor leo. Cras libero magna, mattis in ligula a, rutrum volutpat libero. Morbi tincidunt lectus eget vehicula eleifend. Nullam pulvinar sapien non porttitor pharetra. Fusce porttitor nunc sit amet iaculis rhoncus. Nullam et est vel enim commodo interdum ac vel odio. Duis pretium lorem ante, condimentum laoreet lectus aliquam at. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Praesent ornare dui vel erat hendrerit, commodo tempus eros vehicula. Morbi dapibus est tristique ligula consequat adipiscing. Nulla non massa nibh. Praesent justo quam, eleifend sed blandit eget, pharetra in augue.
        </p>
        <p>
        Vestibulum tincidunt erat at justo adipiscing condimentum. Morbi ante eros, sagittis at augue a, feugiat malesuada quam. Mauris molestie leo a mi accumsan pretium. Vestibulum tempus mi et sagittis convallis. In ac purus porta nisi congue condimentum. Donec augue lectus, eleifend consectetur suscipit sit amet, volutpat sed enim. Quisque eget enim erat. Cras molestie nisi sed leo elementum, et eleifend est sollicitudin. Quisque sed elit at massa tincidunt vehicula sed non leo. Aenean condimentum, purus et consectetur auctor, nunc diam porttitor sapien, rutrum accumsan nisi lectus at ipsum. Duis blandit nulla felis, a dictum odio egestas pretium. Nullam feugiat justo mi, vel pretium mauris posuere vitae. Duis at adipiscing tortor. Morbi laoreet augue vel ullamcorper venenatis.
        </p>
        <p>
        In porttitor orci nec turpis tempus, in faucibus mauris luctus. Aliquam egestas convallis sollicitudin. Sed congue, ante id porttitor tristique, odio purus molestie lectus, id egestas nisl magna vitae felis. Donec imperdiet lectus sem, vel varius sem aliquam vel. Morbi quis leo suscipit, vulputate nisi at, posuere velit. Duis lorem justo, pharetra id mi ut, egestas laoreet dui. Mauris ultricies libero sit amet ligula porttitor, eget sagittis neque ornare. Suspendisse tristique metus nec auctor volutpat.
        </p>        
        </div> <!-- content -->


 <div id="sidebar">
    <div id="secondary_links">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Menu 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Menu 4</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Menu 5</a></li>
        </ul>
     </div>
 </div>


        <div id="footer">Footer</div>

   </div> <!-- wrapper -->
```

Comment: why is css not posted?

Comment: You sidebar menu hasn't disappeared, but it has dropped down underneath your #content div.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are not using `box-sizing:border-box;`, when zooming out, the size of your divs is actually changing. Your `#content` increased from 556px to 558px, thus your total width surpassed that of the `#wrapper`, which is 898px.

You might want to set:

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
#content {
    width: 558px;
}
#sidebar {
    width: 340px;
}
```

Should solve your problems